# Cordova PushPlugin: android push notification stop working after 30 seconds

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-pushplugin

I'm using PhoneGap PushPlugin with Cordova 4.3.0 on Android and it works mostly fine. https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git

I **can** receive push notifications in the following situations :
- App is in foreground
- App is in background
- App is not running

But as soon as the phone goes to power save (in any of the above situations), I can continue to receive push notifications **during the first 30 seconds**, but then they suddenly don't get through and I can neither hear the notification sound nor the notification icon in the top bar.
Logcat data don't see incoming notifications neither.

EDIT : I tested with the Pushwoosh plugin and it can receive the notifications fine even after the phone goes to power save.

I can't believe I'm the only one to face this issue.
Please adise :)

Comment: did you have the wake lock permission ?

Comment: Hi, yes I did : <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
It actually can wake the phone during 30 seconds after powersave mode

Comment: Any other push working? Like fb's

Comment: Other push notifications work, for example Skype push notif buzz while the phone has been in powersave for a few minutes while the pushPlugin notif don't

Comment: In **Application Manager** goto your app and check if **Show Notification** is checked or not ?

Comment: It is checked, as I said notifications appear until 30 sec after the phone in put on power save ;)